# In angular $http, can I get detailed information on a -1 status code?

Tags: angularjs

Using the $http module in anugular.js can sometimes result in a -1 status code.

I know there are numerous reasons for getting this status code like: timeout, CORS call failing, etc...

Is there a way to get more details on that status code  to differentiate between those reasons?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP -1 is an Angular-based response code which indicates a request was aborted ([see the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)). Unfortunately, the spec doesn't seem to give out much more information other than that.

Diving into the source code of [$httpBackend](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/httpBackend.js) and [$http](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js) seems to indicate that a status code of `-1` is only ever returned if the request is aborted by Angular (or if the request aborts/errors i.e, yes, CORS errors), but no other information is given (at least not easily consumable information). [This line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L1334) appears to corroborate that.

So the upshot of that appears to be: no, -1 errors are opaque errors and you can't determine what caused them (unless you yourself triggered the cancellation).

To be clear, though, there are a few ways you can diagnose the problem.

1. You can `navigator.onLine` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)). This will let you determine whether you are able to actually connect to the network. If this returns false, then you know that the timeout is due to your end. Timeouts caused by the client when talking to the server will be returned as [HTTP 408](https://httpstatuses.com/408). This would let you determine whether the http status code being -1/0 is due to a timeout.
2. If the error is due to CORS or an extension cancelling the request, there's not much you can do as a thick client, so I'm not sure it's worth supporting this use-case. Either way, if the above method fails and you didn't cancel the request yourself, you can deduce the issue will be one of the above reasons.